# What's the meaning of monotonicity concept?

Tags: python, oop, method-resolution-order

i was reading about MRO in python and found the monotonicity concept in C3 linearization. I get the point, but i  was curious about the origin of this concept. Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m having a hard time imagining a meaningful linearisation that is *not* monotonic: it wouldn’t make any sense.

But for what it’s worth the origin of the concept of monotonicity in this context can be traced back to the 1992 publication [*Monotonic Conflict Resolution Mechanisms for Inheritance* by Ducournau, R., M. Habib, M. Huchard, & M. L. Mugnier.](https://paperpile.com/shared/ZsROpN)

In it, the authors examine then-existing linearisation algorithms which were flawed because they did *not* satisfy monotonicity. In other words, those algorithms caused the linearisation chain to be reordered by adding a new subclass to the hierarchy. This property was identified as problematic and subsequently fixed in the C3 linearisation.